# How to bind the selected item in Syncfusion SfListView

Tags: html, blazor, syncfusion, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion-blazor

I have the following razor file:

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Lists;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@page "/main_list"

<h1>Select the items</h1>

<SfListView DataSource="@ShopItems01.ToList()" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem" TValue="ShopItem" TItem="ShopItem">
  <ListViewFieldSettings Text="Description" Id="Id" TValue="ShopItem" />
</SfListView>

<SfListView DataSource="@ShopItems02.ToList()" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem" TValue="ShopItem" TItem="ShopItem">
  <ListViewFieldSettings Text="Description" Id="Id" TValue="ShopItem" />
</SfListView>

<SfListView DataSource="@ShopItems03.ToList()" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem" TValue="ShopItem" TItem="ShopItem">
  <ListViewFieldSettings Text="Description" Id="Id" TValue="ShopItem" />
</SfListView>

@code {

  public ShopItem SelectedItem {get; set;}

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    ShopItems01 = await GetItems(id: 0);
    ShopItems02 = await GetItems(id: 1);
    ShopItems03 = await GetItems(id: 2);
  }

  public void Select()
  {
    var itemId = SelectedItem.Id; //always throws null reference exception
  }    
}
```

The bind for the DataSource always works but it can't bind the selected item.
I checked the documentation and they offer all kinds of datasource binding but there is no sign of the selected item.

The [closest thing](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/listview/how-to/get-selected-items-from-listview/) is some kind of HTML DOM access with @ref and using each `SfListView` to get its `SelectedItems` property. I bet it works and I reckon also could use some DOM code with `document.getElementById()` but the whole point of using .Net is to avoid using these kinds of approach.

```
<SfListView @ref="@SfList"
        DataSource="@DataSource"
        ShowCheckBox="true">
   <ListViewFieldSettings TValue="ListDataModel" Id="Id" Text="Text"></ListViewFieldSettings>
</SfListView>

async void OnSelect()
{
  var items = await SfList.GetSelectedItems();
  if (items.Data != null)
  {
    SelectedItems = items.Data;
    this.StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Hypothetically, what if I have 20-30 ListView objects? Should I check *each reference* to find the selected item?

So, any idea how I could create a working binding for the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

The ListView component doesn’t allow to select items by default. When streamline this component to Blazor standard in 2020 Volume 3 release, we have deprecated all the selection related APIs, methods, and events.

Find the details in the below release notes.

https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/release-notes/18.3.35/?type=all#listview

So, you couldn’t bind the selected item directly. But you can check an item using ShowCheckbox property and CheckItems method in ListView.

```
<SfButton Content="data" ID="button" OnClick="click"></SfButton>
    <SfListView @ref="@SfList"
                DataSource="@ListData"
                ShowCheckBox="true">
        <ListViewFieldSettings TValue="DataModel" Id="Id" Text="Text"></ListViewFieldSettings>
    </SfListView>
    @code{
        SfListView<DataModel> SfList;
        public List<DataModel> ListData = new List<DataModel>
         {
            new DataModel() { Text = "Jenifer",Id = "1"},
            new DataModel() { Text = "Amenda", Id = "2"},
    
        };
        async void click()
        {
           await this.SfList.CheckItems(ListData);      
        }
        public class DataModel
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
```